# Let WPF Tabcontrol height assume height of largest item?

Tags: wpf, height, tabcontrol, multibinding

Is there any way to have to tabcontrol take the size of the largest tab item (well, actually, the tabitem's content)?

Since the tabcontrol has no specific size assigned it should autosize: it does that correctly, but when you switch tabs it automatically resizes itself to the height (and width) of the contents of the currently selected tab.

I don't want the resizing to happen, and let the tabcontrol assume the height of the largest item, but still have it autosize itself.

Any clues? I tried databinding to the `Height` property of each element used as content to the  using a multibinding, with bindings on both the `ActualHeight` and the `Items` properties of the Tabcontrol. But alas, the `ActualHeight` of the content elements is always 0.

```
        <TabItem Header="Core" > 
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <Grid.Height>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{Converters1:AllTabContentEqualHeightConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}"/>
                        <Binding Path="Items" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Grid.Height>

            ...
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it was easier to solve that I thought.
Since I had a controltemplate for the `TabControl` anyway, I set the height of the `ContentPresenter` presenting the selected tab content. I do this using a converter that binds to the items of the `TabControl`, measures them if necessary (using `Measure`) and checks `DesiredSize` for the size I need.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var items = value as ItemCollection;

        if (items == null)
            return null;

        double max = 0;
        foreach (TabItem item in items)
        {
            var content = item.Content as FrameworkElement;
            if (content == null) continue;

            if (!content.IsMeasureValid)
                content.Measure(new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue));

            var height = content.DesiredSize.Height;
            if (max < height)
                max = height;
        }

        return max;
    }
```

That works just fine, with some caveats:

- every tab content should be a `FrameworkElement`
- the contents don't change size once they are loaded (because the converter is only called when the Items property changes, ie just once).

Comment: Hi @Inferis could you tell me how you bound to the collection of TabItem inside the tab control? I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Answer (score 28):

Yes it can be done: [reuse-grid-rowdefinitions-for-each-tabitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416674/reuse-grid-rowdefinitions-for-each-tabitem)

Example:

```
    <TabControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="xxx"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="xxx"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
   </TabControl>
```

Comment: The key is to include `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"`, I missed that the first time - without it nothing changed for me.  Also note that you don't have to have the `TabControl` within a grid to apply that value.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this though a DataTemplate? I've got a TabControl bound to a collection to populate it's tabs. I tried setting Row and Column definitions to share Width/Height across all tabs without success (I do Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" set on the TabControl)

Comment: This solution works indeed. I tried it in a data template. But it may cause the UI to be very slow. Depending on where the data template is used.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the `TabControl` unloads and reloads its content as you switch tabs. Therefore it only knows about the size of the content in the currently active tab. You should be able to change the TabControl such that it *never* destroys its children, and they are always present (but maybe hidden).

[This blog post](http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28) by Eric Burke should get you started. From what I can tell by skimming his post, you will need to change it such that:

- All children are loaded when the `TabControl` is loaded.
- Children are hidden rather than collapsed when they are inactive

Comment: That seems a good approach, but I just solved it myself. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in conjunction with `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` approach shown above.

Note that `SetCurrentValue` is used instead of just setting the `SelectedIndex` property - this way we keep possible existing bindings:

```
private void TabControl_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //NOTE: loop through tab items to force measurement and size the tab control to the largest tab
    TabControl tabControl = (TabControl)sender;

    // backup selection
    int indexItemLast = tabControl.SelectedIndex;

    int itemCount = tabControl.Items.Count;

    for (
        int indexItem = (itemCount - 1);
        indexItem >= 0;
        indexItem--)
    {
        tabControl.SetCurrentValue(Selector.SelectedIndexProperty, indexItem);
        tabControl.UpdateLayout();
    }

    // restore selection
    tabControl.SetCurrentValue(Selector.SelectedIndexProperty, indexItemLast);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not in the proper WPF way, but, if you already have all the content elements, you could maybe loop through them on load and set the height of the `TabControl` programatically.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (in conjunction is Grid.IsSharedSizeScope) although one have to call `TabControl.UpdateLayout()` on every tab selected programmatically to force layout measurement.