# TabItems with same size

Tags: xaml, tabitem

I'm using tabitems for separating some information but as each one has different information, each one has a different size. I wonder how I could make both have the same size just changing the XAML file.

Basically, the code I did is:

```
 <WrapPanel>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Client Name" />
                <TextBox MinWidth="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding Path=ClientName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" MaxWidth="200" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Date" />
                <TextBox  MinWidth="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding Path=ClientDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" MaxWidth="200" />
                <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top">

                    <TabItem ..>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem ..>
                    </TabItem>

                </TabControl>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Button ../>
                    <Button ../>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </WrapPanel>
```

Regards
Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 
[Let WPF Tabcontrol height assume height of largest item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073770/let-wpf-tabcontrol-height-assume-height-of-largest-item)

Comment here if it doesn't help

Comment: hi @biju how to remain the width of tabitems should be equal if i open multiple tab items