# TabControl with same height tab items?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Quick question: I've got a TabControl that contains several TabItems. When I switch tabs, the TabControl resizes itself based on the content of the selected (visible) tab - I assume this is standard behaviour. Is there any way to "lock" the TabControl's width & height to that of its largest TabItem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Removed non-answer.

But, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073770/let-wpf-tabcontrol-height-assume-height-of-largest-item?rq=1), that might help.

Comment: I missed the one with the `SharedSizeGroup` trick - this is a slick way of doing it!

Comment: Yeah, after looking at that other post... does my answer of binding to the actual height even work?

Comment: It didn't tbh, and the grid trick didn't work too well either. It only adjusts once the user has visited the other tabs - I guess WPF needs to render them first, so it knows how big they are before it can apply the SharedSizeGroup. Back to the drawing board...!